# Fitting the image to the grid so it takes all available space

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to create simple 2x2 image grid.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .imagewrapper {
  width: 50%;
}

.container img {
  width: calc(100% - (5px * 2));
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks something like that with little bit more styles:

[image]

But when I load a photo in place of placeholders it becomes:

[image]

I would like the image to always occupy the same space as placeholder. Not stretched. I have been looking into the `object-fit` property but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to do it.

TLDR: I would like to create a 2x2 responsive width grid. Where all images regardless of ratio occupy the same space.

Any idea how can I create such a grid? I am happy to use different html if required.

EDIT:

When I change `.container img` to:

```
.container img {
  width: calc(100% - (5px * 2));
  height: 158px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

This is something I will be happy with. But the problem is that **I had to fix the `height`** and I would like to keep it responsive if possible.

Comment: Just put a width and a height to your `.container img` ? Keeping just the width will keep the aspect ratio. Though, this will stretch. Not sure how you want it to cover and be same size while not being stretched

Comment: I have added small edit to the question explaining how not to stretch with `object-fit`. The problem with this is that I need to fix height and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the image a height as well so it "knows" which height to cover.

// **EDIT:** After an update to the question, it stated that no fixed height should be used. In that case, give the img tag a height of 100% and add `align-items: stretch` to the flex-container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.container .imagewrapper {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .imagewrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/e61ce6/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x350/1ecfe6/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x150/ffcc00/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x100/297984/fff" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If the grid is actually fixed as being 2x2 and you want to fill the entire page, you might be better off with actually using grid (instead of flexbox):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50vw 50vw;
  grid-template-rows: 50vh 50vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container .imagewrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .imagewrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/e61ce6/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x350/1ecfe6/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x150/ffcc00/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x100/297984/fff" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no way to do it without fixing height? I would like to have this as responsive design. If I give the grid more space horizontally I would expect the grid squares to grow proportionally. So we would still have 2x2 grid but with wider and taller squares. If I fix height I can't do it.

Comment: See my updated answer, you need to stretch the flex items.

Comment: I also added an example on using a grid display for a full page 2x2 grid.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much. I used your grid design and one thing I have changed was to use `grid-template-rows: 50vw 50vw;`. So the height is always equal to width hence the grid is always squares.